# What does the "Enable Advanced Printing Features" option do?

Tags: windows, printer, printing, print-spooler

When I go to look at a printer's properties in Windows XP, I see a checkbox for "Enable Advanced Printing Features."  What does this option do?

(Specifically, I'm using a Zebra S4M label printer, but I believe this option is available for printers throuh the "printer properties" dialog in Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Basically this checkbox decides (but not by itself alone) whether print jobs are rendered to the printer's native page description language (e.g. PCL or PostScript) on the client (when disabled) or on the server (when enabled). See [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160131175021/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/10/23/disabling-advanced-print-features.aspx) for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I googled 10 minutes about this and found the following:

> Depends on what the particular printer driver supports. Help on it says
>   it enables 'metafile spooling' and such facilities as Page Order;
>   Booklet Printing and Pages per sheet.

Source: [http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums...](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-422689.php)

Thats also what i thought. It really depends on which specific driver or printer you are using.

Comment: I had googled it as well but didn't really find anything that helped explain it very well.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: no problem. It´s kind of an interesting question because it´s something I never thought about. The checkbox was just always there ^^